# Alternative ways to indicate a boolean value on a method

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I am currently trying to refactor some duplicate code. There is one statement in particular which is giving me the most trouble:

```
some_class = double("some_class", some_method?: true)
```

I need to replace some_method with a variable name. However, the below won't work. Below is just an example of what I am trying to do.

```
some_method = unique_method
some_class = double("some_class", some_method?: true)
```

Does any know of alternative way to write:

```
some_method? # where some_method is a var.
```

I need to be able to call

```
some_class.some_method?
```

for my test case.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround that with a string, it should be fine, alternatively you could use the `:some_method? => value`  syntax.

```
def some_method?
  puts "I am some_method?  True"
end

some_hash_key = {:some_method? => true}
send(:some_method?)
my_variable = :some_method?
send(my_variable)          
p some_hash_key
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would do this by passing in a parameter?

Comment: Sorry.. to be more explicit, how I would pass in the method name <some_method> as a parameter to a function or method.     def do_it(method_name)

Comment: Thank you vgoff I needed to work it out, but you got me going in the right direction. I am marking this as the answer. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

OK.. so at the end of the day, the above worked.. here is a working example of what I was trying to do.. I am using a lambda to simulate the function

```
some_method_one = lambda { return }
some_method_one = lambda { return }

picked_method = some_method_one
some_class = double("some_class", picked_one?: true )
some_class.picked_one? # this returns true
```

This code is completely over simplified. What I am intending to do (haven't finished writing the logic yet) is to create a shared_examples_for in rspec. I have 4 methods that will use the same logic for testing, so I need to pass in the method as a variable. Hopefully this makes sense, and helps someone out.. :-)